# Same code for printf, different output?

Tags: c, struct, printf

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct cbor {
  cbor_type type;

  uint64_t length; //x2 for maps

  struct cbor* child;
  struct cbor* next;
  struct cbor* parent;

  union {
    const uint8_t* bytes;
    long sint;
    uint64_t uint;
    double real;
  } value;
} cbor;
```

I initialize a pointer to cbor with malloc, and set length to 0, and value uint and sint to 1, and type to CBOR_INTEGER.

I have a function that should print info about cbor struct:

```
void cbor_print_item(cbor* item){
    os_printf("c2 = %d %d %d\n", item->value.sint, item->value.uint, item->length);

    switch(item->type){
        case CBOR_INTEGER:
            os_printf("type:integer\nsval:%d\nuval:%d\nlength:%d\n", item->value.sint, item->value.uint, item->length);
            os_printf("type:integer\n");
            os_printf("sval:%d\n", item->value.sint);
            os_printf("uval:%d\n", item->value.uint);
            os_printf("length:%d\n", item->length);
            break;
        case CBOR_STRING:
            os_printf("type:\tstring\n");
            os_printf("val:\t%s\n", item->value.bytes);
            os_printf("length:\t%d\n", item->length);
            break;
        case CBOR_REAL:
            os_printf("type:\treal\n");
            os_printf("length:\t%d\n", item->length);
            os_printf("val:\t%f\n", item->value.real);
            break;
        default:
            os_printf("error!\n");
    }
}
```

However, I don't get the expected output. The output for printf's in switch should be the same, right?
My output is:

```
c2 = 1 1 0
type:integer
sval:1
uval:1
length:0
type:integer
sval:1
uval:144
length:144
```

I'm writing code for espressif, hence the "os_printf", as far as I know, it work as "printf".

I'm really baffled and cant find out why this is happening.

EDIT 1: **I know that I shouldn't use "%d" for long and uint64.**
The question is why are the outputs different?
I don't change the values between printing, so the same values should be printed.

EDIT 2: This question isn't about unions, their initialization, best way of printing uint64 or long.

The question is why does

```
os_printf("type:integer\nsval:%d\nuval:%d\nlength:%d\n", item->value.sint, item->value.uint, item->length);
```

print

```
type:integer
sval:1
uval:1
length:0
```

and

```
    os_printf("type:integer\n");
    os_printf("sval:%d\n", item->value.sint);
    os_printf("uval:%d\n", item->value.uint);
    os_printf("length:%d\n", item->length);
```

prints

```
type:integer
sval:1
uval:144
length:144
```

Comment: Why are you using `%d` format specifier for `long` and `uint64_t` types? And why do you think that members of a union that you didn't explicitly set will have a meaningful value?

Comment: i've set them explicitly, length, value.uint and value.sint.

and the output should be the same anyway, right? even if i didn't initialize them and used the wrong format. the only difference is that in first case I printf everything with one printf, and in the second i call three printf's

Comment: If you set `sint` *after* you set `uint` then `uint` no longer has a meaningful value.

Comment: Enable warnings on your compiler and you should get a warning about using `%d` for a `long` and `uint64_t` as Weather Vane mentioned (I think gcc warns about these by default actually).

Comment: sint is set first, and anyway it shouldn't matter for question (as far as I understand it)

Comment: So does MSVC, by default. If you want to use the value of `uint` then you have to explicitly set it first, but you have garbled it by writing to `sint`. Do you understand that the members of a `union` overlay each other?

Comment: From your question edit, you knowingly have *undefined behaviour* so don't ask anyone to explain that.

Comment: From your second edit: the result is undefined. If it could be correctly explained, it would be defined behaviour, but it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have undefined behavior because you are trying to print a `uint64_t` using the `%d` format. `printf` (and other functions that take a variable number of arguments) needs to know the type (and size) of the arguments. It gets this information from the format specifiers. Because you gave it `%d` instead of the correct format it's trying to read an `int` instead of a `uint64_t`. See [this](https://ideone.com/ErFY6n) as an example.

Comment: %lld for uint64_t and %ld for long solved the problem, so i accepted this answer.

Still don't get it why if I print everything in one printf it works differently from when i print in several printf's, but I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You should use the macro `PRIu64` as the format specifyer for `uint64_t` (i.e. `"%" PRIu64` as seen in my example). `%lld` is for `long long` (signed, not unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

with `sprintf(format, val1, val2)` you put val1 and val2 on the paramter stack to sprintf, and then sprintf will fetch values from that stack according to the format string, which is blindly running over the values, not knowing the actual sizes.
so in quintessenz: undefined behaviour